# Disable Auto load of JBoss News Blogs info in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, configuration, jboss, eclipse-juno

I am using Eclipse JUNO SR1 and installed JBoss Tools from official site.
Everything is fine except some annoying features which's causing my eclipse to perform slow

When I open Eclipse, it's showing up JBoss start up page where it's loading JBoss blog information and News and some JBoss tutorials.
They keep on progressing may be due to some firewall settings or whatever reason.

I want to disable all such useless loadings at startup of Eclipse or at any point of time.

I am aware of Eclipse startup settings. However lot of Jboss features are turned on there. What should i do to disable all such useless external informations/fetching of data.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Ok, I found it.

Go to Menu > Window > Preferences > JBoss Tools > JBoss Central and uncheck *Show JBoss Central On Startup*

Comment: I have Luna, but no Jboss Tools. Instead i have Jboss Runtime Detection. How can I disable the updates? In the startup settings I unchecked all Jboss items.

Comment: In latest release under  JBoss Tools > Red Hat Central" instead of JBoss Tools > JBoss Central

Comment: I'm running Eclipse NEON and the checkbox is there, bit it does not work. It keeps popping up.

Answer (score 6):

There is an easier way to do it. On the JBoss tab, there is a wheel icon on the top right corner. Clicking on it, it shows a checkbox to disable showing this tab on start up.

[image: Jboss start page]

Cheers.

Comment: Clicking the checkbox shows a dialog claiming that showonstartup was set to false. This however does not have any further effect. Next time you start eclipse you get the Red Hat Central again.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions you can find it in Window > Preferences > JBoss Tools > Red Hat Central, and disable Show RedHat Central On Startup